# How to save a file in postgresql and retrieve it?

Tags: database, postgresql, file, go

I am trying to get the details of the customer like photograph, adhar, and other identity and bank details in pdf format. I wanted these details to be saved in PostgreSQL. Which is the best format I can store in DB? I will also have access to those files in DB whenever I need them. There won't be much update process in the files though.

I have the file in my Golang server in multipart.File type.

```
type DocumentsAll struct{
    
    Photograph          multipart.File `json:"photograph"`

    Identityproof        multipart.File `json:"identityproof"`
}
```

this is the struct I have that contains all files

My column in db is as follows

ALTER TABLE LOANS ADD column Documentlist bytea;

ie column that contains documents is of data type bytea.

when i try to save document with these format this is what is getting stored in db

> \x7b2270686f746f6772617068223a7b7d2c22706f69223a6e756c6c2c22706f72223a6e756c6c2c2273616c617279736c697073223a6e756c6c2c2262616e6b73746174656d656e74223a6e756c6c2c2263686571756573223a6e756c6c2c22706f6a223a6e756c6c2c22706f6f223a6e756c6c2c22706f71223a6e756c6c2c226c6f616e41677265656d656e74223a6e756c6c2c227369676e766572696679223a6e756c6c2c22656373223a6e756c6c2c227365637572697479636865717565223a6e756c6c2c22706f74223a6e756c6c2c22697472223a6e756c6c2c226c6f616e73746174656d656e74223a6e756c6c7d

So when I try to access it back, I am not able to retrieve the file.

Comment: That looks correct. Your client has to read these bytes and interpret them correctly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you saving file in the db? Why don't you store file on server and add the file path to the database?

Comment: Don't know why the OP needs to, but I can tell you I work on AWS Postgresql and there are EC2 instances that get repaved, hence all files saved disappear. No, we can't request persistent disk file systems for those, so I can see the use case. In my case I'm trying to save HTML files in the database, which is quite tricky. I might end up gzipping the HTML file and save the compressed file in the DB as a bytea column.